# How Insert or append the Result to ADX

Tags: azure-data-factory, kql, adx

I have One Lookup Activity In ADF where o am reading rows from Kusto(ADx) table and write that rows into another ADx table .

But I am getting command issue.

Pipeline:

[image]

Lookup Activity:

```
Test_emg1
| project splitted=split(output, ',')
| mv-expand id=splitted[0]
|mv-expand Start=splitted[1]
| mv-expand End=splitted[2]
|project id,Start,End
```

Update ADx command:

```
@concat('.set-or-append Test_final <| (',activity('Test__final').output')')
```

Error:

getting synatx Error.

Comment: it'd help if you include the full error message, and/or an activity ID. without those, i can only guess that it has to do with the fact you're using single quotes in both the internal query and the call to `@concat()`, and either escaping or changing the quote type may be required

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I have just reform my query.
like.
@concat('.set-or-append Test_final <| print(dynamic(',activity('Test__final').output')'))

Now its working fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).